# Prove that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} = 0$

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

Prove that $$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} = 0.$$

The only why I can think about is using the [Sandwich theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Squeeze_theorem).

Because $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} = 0$, then I just need to find $h(x,y)$ such that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} h(x,y) = 0$ such that:

$$0 \le \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} \le h(x).$$

How can I find $h(x)$?

EDIT:

So what is wrong with my [wolframalpha query](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x,y%29-%3E%280,0%29%20%28x%5E3y%29/%28x%5E6%20%2b%20y%5E2%29)? why is it says the limit is zero?

Comment: Is $\frac{x^{3}y}{x^{6}+y^{2}}$ always non-negative? Even for points arbitrarily close to the origin?

Comment: @ThomasE. What do you mean?

Comment: @user1798362 : You have written $0 \le \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2} \le h(x)$.. Mr.Thomas wants to know if $\frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}$ is always positive.. what does this equal to at $(-1,1)$

Comment: @user1798362: What if $x^3 = y$?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This limit is not equal to $0$ . When the limit exists , if you come by any path to that point the limit should be the same and it should be finite .

You can verify that if I go to the point $(0,0)$ by using $ y = x $ the limit tends to $0$ but when I use $y = x^3$ , the limit comes to be $0.5$ . Hence the limit does not exist

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29+%28x%5E3y%29%2F%28x%5E6+%2B+y%5E2%29

So why is wolframAlpha says the limit is 0?

Comment: I think it depends on what type of algorithm they are using to find the limit . Any algorithm can't cover all the paths ( I think so ) that is why the erroneous limit .

Answer (score 2):

For $ y=mx^3$,

$$ \frac{x^3y}{x^6 + y^2} =\frac{m}{1+m^2} $$

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=lim%28x%2Cy%29-%3E%280%2C0%29+%28x%5E3y%29%2F%28x%5E6+%2B+y%5E2%29

So why is wolframAlpha says the limit is 0?

Comment: @user1798362: wolframalpha calculate wrong! This limit depend on the variable m, thus limit does not exist

Answer (score 1):

In particular if you use $y=mx^3$ and proceed to evaluate the limit along this path then

$\lim_{(x,mx^3)\to(0,0)} \frac{x^3y}{x^6+y^2}=\frac {m}{1+m^2}$ and for different values of $m$ you will have different limit values